# Migrating from Oracle BI to IBM Cognos BI

Tags: cognos

our organization is evaluating the possibility of replacing Oracle Business Intelligence with IBM Cognos Business Intelligence.

My question is, does a tool exist that can assist us with migrating from Oracle BI to Cognos BI or are we required to create our environment from scratch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Cognos Framework Manager tool may allow you to import your Oracle designer dat file.

Import tool: Oracle Oracle Designer 1.3.2, 2.1.2, 6.0, 6i to 10g (http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/designer/index.html)
Import interface: [Data Modeling] Multi-Model, Data Store (Physical Data Model, Logical Data Model) via DAT File from Oracle Designer Import bridge: 'OracleDesigner' 9.1.0 - 2017-04-03 17:26:09

This bridge imports an E/R Model, or a Server Model from an Oracle Designer .DAT file.
Please refer to the bridge File parameter for details on how to generate the .DAT file.

Any given .DAT file may contain:
* an E/R Model (with entities), 
* a Server Model (with tables), 
* many Database Implementation Models (with table implementations).

Ironside may also offer services around this as discussed in the Migrate from Oracle to CA case study: https://www.ironsidegroup.com/case-study/migrate-oracle-discoverer-cognos-analytics/